# How to print RDLC Report in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, rdlc

I want to print my RDLC report in Firefox but the Print button icon is not displaying in Firefox browser but It works fine in IE.

Can anyone guide me how to print my report in Firefox browser.

Comment: You mean you can see the report in ReportViewer but the toolbar have no print button on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to print an rdlc report in firefox.

Rdlc print is only works in ie, due to the activeX requirements.
More info here:[Configuring and Using the ReportViewer Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251670%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

There is an article on msdn about how print a local report without preview, but its only works with winforms report viewer. In asp.net you cannot acces to the client's printer.
[Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Instead of print in firefox, you can export rdlc directly.
For an example:

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
string mimeType = string.Empty;
string encoding = string.Empty;
string extension = string.Empty;
string filename = "YourFileName";


// Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "YourReportHere.rdlc";


byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);


// Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
```